# Deadlock Error in Mutually Concurrent Go Routines

Tags: go, concurrent-programming, goroutine

I have three concurrent go routines like below,

```
func Routine1() {
    mutex1.Lock()

    do something

    mutex2.Lock()
    mutex3.Lock()
    send int to routine 2
    send int to routine 3
   * Print Something *
    mutex2.Unlock()
    mutex3.Unlock()

    receive ints
    do something 

    mutex2.Lock()
    mutex3.Lock()
    send int to routine 2
    send int to routine 3
    Print Something
    mutex2.Unlock()
    mutex3.Unlock()

    do something
    receive ints
    mutex1.Unlock()
    wg.Done()
}

func Routine2() {
    mutex2.Lock()

    do something

    mutex1.Lock()
    mutex3.Lock()
    send int to routine 1
    send int to routine 3
    Print Something
    mutex1.Unlock()
    mutex3.Unlock()

    do something
    receive ints

    mutex1.Lock()
    mutex3.Lock()
    send int to routine 1
    send int to routine 3
    Print Something
    mutex1.Unlock()
    mutex3.Unlock()

    do something
    receive ints
    mutex2.Unlock()
    wg.Done()
}

func Routine3() {
// same structure as routine 1 & 2
}
func main() {
wg.Add(3)
go Routine1()
go Routine2()
Routine3()
wg.Wait()
}
```

This logical code gives deadlock situation every time. Actually, when it runs, just execute print statement of routine 1 (statement between * marks) manytimes (though my print statement is only one) and gives deadlock error. Can anybody inform me what is wrong with the code logic. Thanks.

NB. For more info, code can be found here, http://play.golang.org/p/pW6aXryUaK, where only line number 290 is executing.  The original code which contains no error, can be found here play.golang.org/p/UL3rj8DJRk. I just add lock and unlock to them. Thanks.

**I want to add another point: in the code of play.golang.org/p/UL3rj8DJRk, you can find outputs of various print statements like this: process [number] sends [int] to process [number] at   [time nano seconds]. However, as the result of three concurrent routines, sometimes the print statement is not executing properly (means not printing whole, there is some thing inserted by another print like process [number] sends [int] to process [number] at process [number]). Can any body help me how to manage this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to identify the cause of the deadlock because the code you posted does not contain enough information.

It may be caused by the order in which you are acquiring locks, or it may be caused by usage of unbuffered Go channels.

Until you post complete Go source code, there is no way to answer your question.

If you need to discuss the code in greater length, you probably should post it to [golang-nuts](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts?pli=1).

Comment: The complete code, you can find on http://play.golang.org/p/pW6aXryUaK, where only line number 290 is executing. Thanks.

Comment: One more addition, the original code which contains no error, can be found here http://play.golang.org/p/UL3rj8DJRk. I just add lock and unlock to them.

Comment: @Arpssss: Your code isn't idiomatic Go code. It is a mess. You are using locks and buffered channels for no reason. Post your code (http://play.golang.org/p/pW6aXryUaK) to http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts - hopefully, people at golang-nuts will help you to improve the code.

Comment: Thanks Atom for your suggestion. However, in the original posts pseudo code, is there any reason to execute just only print statements multiple times ?